# XSS Prevention in classic asp with CKEditor input

Tags: asp-classic, ckeditor, xss, owasp

I am currently working on a classic asp project and am using the CKEditor plugin to get user input. I want to try and prevent XSS attacks in my project. Removing the script tags is easy, the tricky part is dealing with the attributes within html tags without removing the tags completely.
I found a lot of javascript based solutions but i want my code to be on the server side for security reasons.

I tried a simple replace method like so:

```
CleanedHTML = Replace(HTML,"onmouseover","[removed]",1,-1,1)
```

But this will also remove the word if it is not between tags.

I have gone thru OWASPs website and I also have a function which removes all tags that i found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/639/Removing-HTML-from-the-text-in-ASP) but i can't use it since i want to allow users to enter links, images etc. Is there any safe way to accomplish this?

Comment: why you are using a tool like CKEditor when you do not want html code? html code is not malicious? javascrip COULD be malicious. you will habve no success by trying to remove "dangerous" tags or attrributes. you will have to make sure that user inputs are encoded at the time you show it on the client

Comment: I want to allow html code. If i do a regular `server.HTMLEncode()` it escapes all html characters which is as good as showing the source back to the user. The idea is to allow the user to save links and images etc without compromising on security.

Comment: then just remove the script tags. i think ckeditor has a Feature for that?

Comment: I am removing the script tags. i want to remove malicious code like `<a onmouseover="alert('hello')">Bad Code</a>` CKEditor does not handle this by default

Comment: Add an equals sign to your replace statement, for example: Replace(HTML,"onmouseover=","[removed]",1,-1,1)

Comment: @NathanRice : No that won't work in case the user enters something like `<a onmouseover ="alert('hello')">Bad Code</a>`. Note the space before the "=" sign

Comment: You could account for both cases. I also have another function that looks for doublespaces, so you could run it through a similar function that removes doublespaces beforehand.